# Why wasn't the Meta-Crisis Doctor as smart as Doctor Donna was?

Tags: doctor-who

He was half-human, half-Time Lord. Why couldn't he be as smart as Donna was?

Also, why didn't he have complications and need to have his own memory wiped, like Doctor Donna?

Comment: Perhaps because he wasn't linked to that well known mental titan, Donna Noble

Answer (score 1):

This quote from the upgraded Donna may have the answer (emphasis mine):

> He poured all his regeneration energy into his spare hand. I touched the hand, and he grew out of that but that fed back into me. But, it just stayed dormant in my head till the synapses got that little extra spark, kicking them into life. Thank you, Davros! Part human, part Time Lord. And **I got the best bit of the Doctor. I got his mind.**

Since the Meta-Crisis Doctor and the Doctor-Donna both emerged out of the Doctor at the same time, maybe both of them got different "parts" of him: one got his body, the other got his mind.

---

On the other hand, **why do you think the Meta-Crisis Doctor wasn't as smart as the Doctor-Donna?** He seems plenty smart, equally much so as the original Doctor, and all three of them handle the complicated technical task of returning the seventeen planets together. He's physically somewhat Donna-ified, with his single heart and his "rough" South London accent, but mentally he seems well up to being a Doctor. The only thing that he (and the original Doctor) don't have, according to Donna, is human instinctive inspiration:

> NEW DOCTOR: What did you do?
> DONNA: Trip switch circuit-breaker in the psychokinetic threshold manipulator.
> NEW DOCTOR: But that's brilliant!
> DOCTOR: Why did we never think of that?
> DONNA: Because you two were just Time Lords, you dumbos, lacking that little bit of human. That gut instinct that comes hand in hand with Planet Earth. I can think of ideas you two couldn't dream of in a million years.

Note that she (and the original Doctor) lump both of the two Doctors together in this, not implying any difference between them in intelligence, knowledge, or mental ability.